# remove the item in string

Tags: string, python-3.x

How do I remove the other stuff in the string and return a list that is made of other strings ? This is what I have written. Thanks in advance!!!

```
    def get_poem_lines(poem):
r""" (str) -> list of str

Return the non-blank, non-empty lines of poem, with whitespace removed 
from the beginning and end of each line.

>>> get_poem_lines('The first line leads off,\n\n\n'
... + 'With a gap before the next.\nThen the poem ends.\n')
['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
"""

list=[]
for line in poem:
    if line == '\n' and line == '+':
        poem.remove(line)
s = poem.remove(line)
for a in s:
    list.append(a)
return list
```

Comment: This is pretty vague unless you post a sample input with your code. Writing a text description doesn't resolve the ambiguity of your problem

Answer (score 1):

`split` and `strip`  might be what you need:

```
s = 'The first line leads off,\n\n\n     With a gap before the next.\nThen the poem ends.\n'

print([line.strip() for line in s.split("\n") if line])
['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
```

Not sure where the `+` fits in as it is, if it is involved somehow either strip or str.replace it, also avoid using `list` as a variable name, it shadows the python `list`.

lastly strings have no remove method, you can .replace but since strings are *immutable* you will need to reassign the `poem` to the the return value of replace i.e `poem =  poem.replace("+","")`

Answer (score 0):

You can read all non-empty lines like this:

```
list_m = [line if line not in ["\n","\r\n"] for line in file];
```

Without looking at your input sample, I am assuming that you simply want your white spaces to be removed. In that case,

```
for x in range(0, len(list_m)):
    list_m[x] = list_m[x].replace("[ ](?=\n)", "");
```

Comment: `if line.strip` will check for empty lines and use enumerate if you are want the index of an iterables elements. Also what is  `"\s"` ? Are you thinking replace is re?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham       I was editing the snippet when you commented....should be different now

Comment: if you `.replace(" ", "")` that will replace all spaces i.e `foo bar foobar -> foobarfoobar `